# QT: How to send signals from C to Qt

Tags: c, qt, signals

Im trying to make an app using qt on frontend and C on backend. In the mainwindow I create a thread that execute my extern C code, but when the code do some things I need to share structures and values with the qt mainwindow. Im thinking on use shared memory and signals to comunicate this info between the c process and the mainwindow. I saw on the qt wiki the QSharedMemory lib but I dont see anything about signals between c code and qt or similar.

Thanks, and sorry for my bad english =/

Comment: C or C++? Its confusing.

Comment: So which is it? A process or a thread?

Comment: The backend is written in C. And I create a thread that execute the C code. I guess that its a thread, its a class that extends from QThread and it call the C Function.

Comment: @user2959046, note that if you're inheriting from QThread, "you're doing it wrong": http://blog.qt.digia.com/blog/2010/06/17/youre-doing-it-wrong/

Comment: This is also worth reading: http://mayaposch.wordpress.com/2011/11/01/how-to-really-truly-use-qthreads-the-full-explanation/

Comment: @Merlin069 Ups. Indeed im doing it wrong. Now I fixed it. Thanks =). But I still having the problem with the signals between c and qt.

Comment: Can you show a some code of how you're trying to use the signals and link the two together?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you're asking correctly, most of the libraries used in C are also accessible in Qt so for the most part you won't have much problem sharing the code. And about sharing structures, since defining structures is identical in both of them you can for example define you structure in a `structure.h` file and then include this file in both of your codes and use it.

Comment: Sure, I understand the part of the structures. But can I insert and extern code like: signal(SIGxxx,signal_handler) on the qt mainwindow class? This is because i need to read the shared memory on specific moments.